# Pandas merge with multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes and I want to combine into a new DF.

```
df1: Category  Locale  Provider  Traffic Weeknumber
     Clickout    AT       A        1200      1
     Clickout    DE       B        3400      2
     Popunder   COM       A        50        1
     Popunder   COM       B        50        2

df2: Device  Locale  Provider Weeknumber Clickout Popunder
     Mobile    AT       A        1        200     300
     Desktop   DE       A        2        2000    1400
     Mobile   COM       B        1        250     500
     Desktop  COM       B        2        100      850
```

What the new dataframe should look like:

```
df3: Category  Locale  Provider  Traffic Weeknumber Mobile Desktop
     Clickout    AT       A        1200      1       500    700
     Clickout    DE       A        3400      2       2000   1400
     Popunder   COM       B        750       1       250    500
     Popunder   COM       B        950       2       100    850
```

I guess there are two steps, with df2 switch the columns clickout and popunder into rows and change the device type into columns. Then merge this with df1 based on Locale, Provider and Weeknumber.

This is what an excel formula looks like (if it helps at all)

```
{=INDEX('Sheet_2'!A:G,MATCH(1,('Sheet_2'!A:A=
[@Locale])*('Sheet_2'!C:C=[@provider])*('Sheet_2'!E:E=[@Weeknumber])*('Sheet_2'!B:B=Sheet_1_crosstab!T$1),0),MATCH([@[source_aggregated]],'Sheet_2'!$A$1:$G$1,0))}
```

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: I think we already went over this. `df2.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you did, but now the input data's slightly changed, it seems. A need to pivot the `Clickout` and `Popunder` columns into row-values under a common column is desired, if I've understood correctly.

Comment: Yes sorry about this (thank you for the help though)! I deleted the question as I realized I had df2 incorrect. Plasma is correct about pivoting Clickout and Popunder.

Comment: It's unclear to me how your `Mobile` and `Desktop` column values are set, though.

Comment: I guess the dummy values don't make any sense. The mobile and desktop values will add up to the Traffic value in df1 for each category,provider, locale and week number. If traffic is 1200, then the combined mobile and desktop values will add up to 1200.